# Integrating the common log of $x$

Tags: integration

Problem:

Perform the following integration.
$$ \int \log(x) \,\, dx $$
Note: $log(x)$ is log base $10$.

Answer:

\begin{align*}
***\int \log(x) \,\, dx &= \int \ln(x) - ln(10) \,\, dx ***\\
\int \log(x) \,\, dx &= \int \ln(x) \,\, dx - \int \ln(10) \,\, dx \\
\int \ln(10) \,\, dx &= \ln(10)x + C_1 \\
\end{align*}
Now we use integration by parts.
\begin{align*}
u &= \ln(x) \\
du &= \frac{dx}{x} \\
dv &= dx \\
v &= x \\
\int \ln(x) \,\, dx &= x \ln(x) - \int \frac{x}{x} \,\, dx \\
\int \ln(x) \,\, dx &= x \ln(x) - x + C_2 \\
\int \log(x) \,\, dx &= x \ln(x) - x + C_2 - (  \ln(10)x + C_1) \\
\int \log(x) \,\, dx &= x \ln(x) - x + C_2 -  \ln(10)x - C_1 \\
\int \log(x) \,\, dx &= x \ln(x) - x  -  \ln(10)x + C \\
\int \log(x) \,\, dx &=  x \ln(x) -  (1 + \ln(10)) x + C  \\
\end{align*}

However, an online integral calculator shows that the answer is:
$$ \dfrac{ x( \ln(x) - 1 ) } { \ln(10) } + C $$
Where did I do wrong?

Comment: $$\log x = \frac{\ln x}{\ln 10}$$

Comment: $\log(x)=\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(10)}$, not $\ln(x) - \ln(10)$

Comment: You went wrong where I put the 3 starts in front and end. Think about it...